# Nginx websocket proxy

Tags: regex, nginx, websocket, proxy, server-configuration

I'm trying to use nginx to proxy websocket requests using a regularexpression as follows:

```
server {
            listen 9092;
            server_name ~^(?<pc_name>.*)\.(.*)$;
            location / {
                    include proxy_params;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_pass http://$pc_name:9092;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            }
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
            default upgrade;
            ''      close;
    }
```

and it's not working like that, i'm getting errors about not being able to resolve the host if i try to access pc-addr.localhost:9092 i get the error:

```
2017/08/07 08:42:37 [error] 22021#22021: *2 no resolver defined to resolve pc-addr, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ~^(?<pc_name>.*)\.(.*)$, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "pc-addr.localhost:9092"
```

However, if I replace the variable name with with pc-addr directly (i.e. all requests will be forwarded to pc-add:9092) it works fine and the requests are proxied as expected

```
server {
            listen 9092;
            server_name ~^(?<pc_name>.*)\.(.*)$;
            location / {
                    include proxy_params;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_pass http://pc-addr:9092;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            }
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
            default upgrade;
            ''      close;
    }
```

Comment: See [this thread](https://serverfault.com/a/649196).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @WiktorStribiżew but that thread is talking about a different problem .. it's trying to add a rewrite while i'm trying to proxy the requests to some other location that's not directly reachable.

Comment: Try adding a `resolver` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for details.

Comment: I added one previously but it didn't help. Also if i directly proxy the requests to `http://pc-addr:9092`, the requests are proxied as expected so it doesn't really seem to be a dns resolution problem or am i missing something here?